# How to reindex and change _type

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

We need to migrate a number of indexes from ElasticSearch 6.8 to ElasticSearch 7.x. To be able to do this, we now need to go back and fix a large number of documents are the `_type` field of these documents aren't `_doc` as required. We fixed this for newer indexes, but some of the older data which we still need has other values in here.

How do we reindex these indexes and also change the `_type` field?

```json
POST /_reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "my-index-2021-11"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "my-index-2021-11-n"
    },
    "script": {
      "source": "ctx._type = '_doc';"
    }
}
```

I saw a post indicating the above might work, but on execution, the value for `_type` in the next index was still the existing of `my-index`.

The one option I can think of is to iterate through each document in the index and add it to the new index again which should create the correct `_type`, but that will take days to complete, so not so keen on doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below should work . Please test it out, before running on actual data

```
{
    "source": {
        "index": "my-index-2021-11"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "my-index-2021-11-n",
        "type":"_doc"
    }
}
```

Docs to help in upgradation

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/reindex-upgrade-inplace.html

Comment: The answer as is isn't the full solution as I did try that before without success, but I got it to work now.

Previously, I would've first created the new index by doing `PUT /my-index-2021-11` along with the mapping document. After that, I would've called the reindex.  Today, ran the reindex without first doing the PUT call and it worked as expected.

Comment: Can confirm on 5.x upgraded to 6.8.8, `PUT` to the index with an *inline* mapping that includes the doc type e.g. `{"mappings": "_doc": { ... everything normally in your mappings... }}` works and then you can do the documented `POST` to `_reindex` into it.